# Create a two-way binding in vue.js between an array and multiple text inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

My data is stored in an array. For each array item, there should be a text input in the form. When the user types into one of the text inputs, the array should be updated with the new values.

```
  <div class="form-group" v-for="synonym in row.synonyms">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="synonym" />
  </div>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/eywraw8t/122210/

The idea is when you type into one of the textboxes, the array value (shown below in that fiddle) should also update, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon inspecting the console, you would find the following error:

> **You are binding v-model directly to a v-for
>   iteration alias.** This will not be able to modify the v-for source
>   array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local
>   variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an
>   object property instead.

Meaning, we need to give `v-model` access to a direct reference to the synonym and its index:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    row: {
     synonyms: [
       "abc", 
        "def", 
        "ghj",
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {

  }
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Exo 2', sans-serif;
}

#app {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <h2>Items</h2>
  <div class="form-group" v-for="(synonym,i) in row.synonyms">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="row.synonyms[i]" />
  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <h3>
  The text below should change if yout type inside the textboxes:
  </h3>
  
  <p>
  {{ JSON.stringify(row)}}
  </p>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm still learning Vue but I'm pretty sure you don't want form-group AND v-for in the same tag. Otherwise, you'll end up with multiple form-group divs.  I'm happy to be corrected if I'm mistaken.

Comment: @ultrageek - it really doesn't matter here, I typically add the `v-for` to a parent because I'm using the contents (in this case, `row.synonyms[i]`) multiple times within the children; here that doesn't really apply, so you could remove the div and use the `v-for` directly on the input.

Comment: It doesn't matter for the loop functionality, but you want the form-group to be an ancestor up, not in where the v-for is. That's all I was pointing out

Comment: @ultrageek - the form group is just a class name I made up, it's entirely irrelevant here. It could be named `foo` and it'd still accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Well Bootstrap has it, and I was using it when I read your comment. So I assumed that's what you were doing. My bad

Comment: @ultrageek ahh I see. I can probably edit it. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do it is to use an index, which vue.js provides in loops:

```
  <div class="form-group" v-for="(synonym, index) in row.synonyms">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="row.synonyms[index]" />
  </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m14vd89u/1/

Comment: Darn, you beat me to the punch

Answer (score 0):

This is the recommended way that Vue.js wants you to do it by using an index `(synonym, index)`:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html

```
<div class="form-group" v-for="(synonym, index) in row.synonyms">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" v-on:blur="onItemsChanged(synonym)" v-model="row.synonyms[index]" />
</div>
```

If you wanted to do it another way you could introduce a method `v-on:blur`:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    row: {
        synonyms: [
        "abc", 
        "def", 
        "ghj",
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onItemsChanged (synonym) {
      // do something with array
    }
  }
})
```