# How to bind to array objects in vue?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have a data array that I want to bind input element entry (integers) into data fields, and then total them.  This is akin to a spreadsheet where it can compute the sum or difference of different values specified in the same column.

I don't understand from vue.js documentation, what it takes to make two-way data binding work on these array objects.  I can't tell if the values are updating in the array.  Either they aren't updating the array, or the summation link is not being updated.  Do you have a recommendation for determining if the data binding is broken, or why the expression is not getting updated?

```
<tr v-for="(row, powerIndex) in powers">
    <td :class="powerlabelclass(row)">{{ row.name }}</td>
    <td class="power-item" v-for="turn in turns">
        <div v-if="row.expression">
            <input :class="poweritemclass(row)" type="number" :tabindex="tabindex(powerIndex, turn)" :value="calculatepower(powerIndex, turn)" />       
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <input :class="poweritemclass(row)" type="number" :tabindex="tabindex(powerIndex, turn)" :value="row.turns[turn]" />        
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ledlogic/fst561by/

Comment: Maybe you want to include the code blocks in question and only link the jsfiddle as a backup? Reading the code from the fiddle is a PITA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fisrt of all - you are missing [v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html) which is necessary for two way binding.

I suggest you try and understand the concept of `v-model` first:

> You can use the v-model directive to create two-way data bindings on
> form input, textarea, and select elements.

Please note that:

-

> v-model will ignore the initial value, checked or selected attributes
> found on any form elements. It will always treat the Vue instance
> data as the source of truth. You should declare the initial value on
> the JavaScript side, inside the data option of your component.

- > For languages that require an IME (Chinese, Japanese, Korean etc.),
  > you’ll notice that v-model doesn’t get updated during IME composition.
  > If you want to cater for these updates as well, use input event
  > instead.

Now for your example:

What it should look like is:

```
<tr v-for="(row, powerIndex) in powers">
    <td :class="powerlabelclass(row)">{{ row.name }}</td>
    <td class="power-item" v-for="turn in turns">
        <div v-if="row.expression">
            <input :class="poweritemclass(row)" type="number" :tabindex="tabindex(powerIndex, turn)" v-model="calculatepower(powerIndex, turn)" />       
        </div>
        <div v-else>
            <input :class="poweritemclass(row)" type="number" :tabindex="tabindex(powerIndex, turn)" v-model="row.turns[turn]" />        
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'd suggest you to look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51094125/create-a-two-way-binding-in-vue-js-between-an-array-and-multiple-text-inputs) for better context.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `v-model` instead of `:value` for 2 way binding

I assume you want to calculate total value automatically. You only need to change:

```
  <div v-else>
     <input :class="poweritemclass(row)" type="number" :tabindex="tabindex(powerIndex, turn)" v-model="row.turns[turn]" />        
  </div>
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/ittus/1z6qu43y/