# The best way of Two-way data binding using vuex in a list

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

[image: img_list_items]

I have a list of items in a **Vuex state**.
According to the image when I checked items the main state would be updated using `v-on:change`
and too in the sidebar but when I toggle down using `v-on:change` (side bar) the Vuex state changes but the checkbox has value!!!
how to handle it using **two-way data binding** in such a scenario?

best regards.

Comment: Please frame your explanation a little better. It doesnt make a lot of sense.

Comment: Also please show your code too.

Comment: Both checkboxes (left and right) must use the same `:value` and handle the `@input` event to update the Vuex store.

Comment: keep in mind that left and right checkboxes are binds to a list

Comment: When some checkboxes are checked then the sidebar was affected otherwise the related checked checkboxes controls were unchecked. tnx for the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the main list in the whole of programs with contains such items:

```
{id:1,text:'a',checked:false}
```

this scenario :

the **Search component** shows pure of list items either checked or not checked.
the **Side Component** shows the items checked properly and then click the close button it should disappear and uncheck items simultaneously.

so Search Component bind to the list by :

```
<input type="checkbox" :value="item.checked" v-model="$store.state.sideBarItems[index].checked">
```

so my answer is `[index].checked` which make a proper two-way data binding.

tnx to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51094190/12450400) post which gives me an idea